# Tkinter removing standard window in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, window, tkinter

Is there a command similar to "wm_overrideredirect" for Ubuntu? I want My program to be displayed without the standard window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu's desktop manager is Gnome, which should support `wm_overrideredirect` as well as any other.  What's going wrong for you when you try that?  Can you show (by editing your Q) some as-tiny-as-possible Python/Tkinter script that does not behave the way you want, and tell us how it *does* behave and how you'd *like* to behave?

Comment: Never mind 'wm_overrideredirect' works. Now how do I destroy the program?

Answer (score 1):

As noted (obliquely) in [the manual](http://docs.python.org/library/tkinter.html#the-window-manager):

```
my_toplevel.master.overrideredirect(True)
```

I tested this on Ubuntu Lucid, compiz window manager, Python 2.6.5. As the WM protocol is ancient, I don't expect the window manager to be an issue.